# Common elements in two dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe

Having two data frame as below:

data frame:1

```
new_data = {
  "Fruits": ['AB', 'AB','BC', 'CD','DE','EG'],
  "price": [50, 30, 45,55,47,43]
}
new_df = pd.DataFrame(new_data)

print(new_df)
```

dataframe:2

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
  "Food": ['AB','AB','BC', 'CE','DE','EF','EM','FB'],
  "Calories": [150, 405, 450,55,47,43,43,23]
}

#load data into a DataFrame object:
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

print(df)
```

need to return the unique values in dataframe1, comparing with the food column in dataframe2.

Expected output

```
 Fruit  Price
0    AB     50
1    AB     30
2    BC     45
3    DE     47
```

return the first dataframe where the food values is in fruit value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`.loc[]`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) with [`.isin()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html) to check if a value in the Fruits from new_df exist in the Food column of df:

```
new_df.loc[new_df['Fruits'].isin(df['Food'])]

  Fruits  price
0     AB     50
1     AB     30
2     BC     45
4     DE     47
```